# Angular ngb-pagination with a Table setup

Tags: angular

I am using ngb-pagination with my angular application and not sure how it is setup! How do I wire the pagination to the getBSAFollowup function in my .ts component (it returns all rows now). also how to initialize [collectionSize]="1" [(page)]="page"

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/pagination/examples

my html

```
<tr *ngFor="let bsa of bsaFollowup| orderBy: key : reverse ; let i = index" (click)="GetfollowupID(bsa.ID)">
                        <td style="width:9%">{{bsa.ErsaID}}</td>
                        <td style="width:18%">{{bsa.Access}}</td>
                                              </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6">
                            <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="1" [(page)]="page" [maxSize]="5" [rotate]="true" [boundaryLinks]="true"></ngb-pagination>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

Component.ts

```
  getBSAFollowup() {
        this._dashboardService.getBSAFollowup()
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.bsaFollowup = data.result;
            },
            error => console.log('GetControls Method: ' + <any>error, 'alert alert-danger'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1>Users</h1>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>UserName</th>
                        <th>FullName</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of pagedItems">
                        <td>{{item.username}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.fullName}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="pager.totalItems" [pageSize]="pager.pageSize" [(page)]="pager.currentPage" [maxSize]="pager.totalPages" [rotate]="true" (pageChange)="setPage(pager.currentPage)" [boundaryLinks]="true"></ngb-pagination>
        </div>
    </div>
```

PaginationService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'underscore';

@Injectable()
export class PaginationService {
    constructor() {}

    getPager(
        totalItems: number,
        currentPage: number = 1,
        pageSize: number = 10
    ) {
        // calculate total pages
        const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);

        let startPage: number, endPage: number;
        if (totalPages <= 10) {
            // less than 10 total pages so show all
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = totalPages;
        } else {
            // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
            if (currentPage <= 6) {
                startPage = 1;
                endPage = 10;
            } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
                startPage = totalPages - 9;
                endPage = totalPages;
            } else {
                startPage = currentPage - 5;
                endPage = currentPage + 4;
            }
        }

        // calculate start and end item indexes
        const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
        const endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

        // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
        const pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);

        // return object with all pager properties required by the view
        return {
            totalItems: totalItems,
            currentPage: currentPage,
            pageSize: pageSize,
            totalPages: totalPages,
            startPage: startPage,
            endPage: endPage,
            startIndex: startIndex,
            endIndex: endIndex,
            pages: pages
        };
    }
}
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppDataService } from '../../services/app-data.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { NgForOf } from '@angular/common';
import { UserDetails } from '../../model/UserDetails';

import * as _ from 'underscore';

import { PaginationService } from '../../shared/pagination/pagination.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit  {
    private  users:  any[] ;
    pager: any = {};
    pagedItems: any[];
    error = '';
    page = 1;

    constructor(private appDataService: AppDataService, private paginationService: PaginationService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadData();
    }

    loadData() {
        this.appDataService.getUsers()
       .subscribe(
        data => {
            //LOAD YOUR DATA 
            this.users = data ;

            this.setPage(1);
         },
         error => {
           this.error = 'Error in calling users!';

         }
       );
    }

    setPage(page: number) {
        if (page < 1 || page > this.pager.totalPages) {
            return;
        }
        if (isNaN(page)) {
            page = 1;
        }

        this.pager = this.paginationService.getPager(this.users.length, page);

        this.pagedItems = this.users.slice(this.pager.startIndex, this.pager.endIndex + 1);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried using this angular2-table before, the issue is I have to have edit on the table with some complex logic..this is why I am using regular tables